# Warning the user/local/mysql/data directory is not owned by the mysql user

Tags: mysql, macos

I can't start the mysql service in Snow Leopard, and in the panel prefs appears the message,

> warning the user/local/mysql/data directory is not owned by the mysql user

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 348):

If you can't start mysql service in snow leopard, and in the panel prefs appears 'warning the user/local/mysql/data directory is not owned by the mysql user', you have to:

- `sudo chown -RL root:mysql /usr/local/mysql`
- `sudo chown -RL mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data`
- `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`

Comment: Apparently this is still biting people - so I've moved your answer into an... Answer. Hope you don't mind...

Comment: for others coming to this now.. this works in El Capitan as well

Comment: Why hasn't this been checked as the correct answer?

Comment: I couldn't get mysql to start after upgrading to El Capitan. This worked for me.

Comment: @zeros-ones Because the OP originally answered it in the question itself and an admin (@Shog9) moved it to an answer. The OP needs to mark it as the correct answer now.

Comment: This randomly started happening to me on Sierra (weeks after updating). Fix still works

Comment: Seriously.. does this happen after *every* macOS update??

Comment: it's working, You save my time on macOS Hight Sierra, Yes @DaveNottage this happened after Sierra update

Comment: Tried this on macOS Mojave and no joy. I get `ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file` when trying `mysql.server start`

Comment: Tried this on MacOS Catalina - I got an error message on the last command (sorry, I didn't save the message) but the server seems to be up and running for me.

Comment: The second command `sudo chown -RL mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data` was sufficient to make it work when starting MySQL Server from the Systems Preferences MySQL control panel. On Catalina.

Answer (score 118):

This work for me in **El Capitan** & **Sierra**

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:wheel /usr/local/mysql/data
```

That's it.

---

**Update: to fix auto start**

I found it more useful if you fix Auto Starting too:

```
sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
```

And paste in:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true />
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mysql.mysqld</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
      <string>--user=mysql</string>
    </array>        
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Save it and then:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
sudo chmod 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
```

Then it will load on a restart.

Reference: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/

Comment: is wheel your own user name, or something special? If that could be clarified that would be great

Comment: [`Wheel`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_%28Unix_term%29)  is (Unix term) refers to a user account with a wheel bit.

Comment: This fixed it in Sierra,  as well.

Comment: What is a 'wheel bit' ?

Comment: 'Wheel bit' is a system setting that provides additional special system privileges that empower a user to execute restricted commands that ordinary user accounts cannot access.