# OSX Warning the user/local/mysql/data directory is not owned by the mysql or _mysql user

Tags: mysql

I have mysql version 5.7.11 on OSX El-Capitan.
I am getting this error while trying to start mysql server after restart.

Comment: how are you starting the mysql server?

Comment: By Going to "System Preferences" -> "mysql" -> "start MySql Server"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've gone through same issue.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527676/warning-the-user-local-mysql-data-directory-is-not-owned-by-the-mysql-user) worked for me. I reproduce the commands suggested there below:

```
sudo chown -RL root:mysql /usr/local/mysql
sudo chown -RL mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Worked for me. :)