# Can't create database mysql

Tags: mysql, macos-sierra

Before starting, I would like to point out that this question is not about the problem:

`Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'something'`

and so, solutions for [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461064/unable-to-create-database-due-access-denied) or similar problems doesn't work.

I think I messed up with some chmod commands and now, I can log into all the users in my mysql installation but cannot create a database in any user. When I use command:

`create database somedatabase;`

I get an error saying,

`ERROR 1006 (HY000): Can't create database 'somedatabase' (errno: 276999488)`

For more information, I don't have a `/var/lib/mysql` directory but I have a `/usr/local/mysql` directory. So,

- Should I use any other commands to identify the actual problem?
- Have I messed up mysql permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below solved my problem:

- `sudo chown -RL root:mysql /usr/local/mysql`
- `sudo chown -RL mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data`
- `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`

[Taken from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27517150/3913366).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and getting latest xcode solved the issue